# How to plot in pandas after groupby function

Tags: pandas, time-series, visualization

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(some data)
df2 = df.groupby(['Country', "Year"]).sum()

It looks like this:

```
             Sales  COGS    Profit  Month Number
Country Year                                    
Canada  2013 3000
Canada  2014 3500
Other countries... other data
```

df3 = df2[[' Sales']]

I can plot it like this with the code:

df3.plot(kind="bar")
And it produces a chart

[image]

But I want to turn it into a line chart but my result from a simple plot is:

[image]

Stuck as to what one-liner will produce a chart that segments time on the x-axis but plots sales on y-axis with lines for different countries.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stack `Country` column:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = df.groupby(['Country', 'Year'])['Sales'].sum().unstack('Country')

# Or df2.plot(title='Sales').set_xticks(df2.index)
ax = df2.plot(title='Sales')
ax.set_xticks(df2.index)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]